# Why can't I find the server I just previously played on in gmod?

Tags: hosting, garrys-mod

I recently played on a server on gmod that I really enjoyed, and I cant find it in my history. Can anybody explain why? I dont think the server shut down because I couldn't find it in the legacy browser while I was in the server...

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe a bug or the server is located somewhere else. People also have problems to find the favorites on the new **GMOD** server searcher.

Click on **"Old Serverbrowser"** and then open up history, you should find the servers you currently played on. Maybe you also see servers from other games too.

Answer (score 1):

There are the options "Server not full", "Has users playing" and "is not password protected", which filter the list. Unticking them shows all entries.

[image: Image that shows the server browser options in GMod]

Comment: This is not an answer. Please write a comment if you want to comment.

Comment: @Fabian updated my answer.